# How to change levels of a variable that is a factor?

Tags: r

I have a data that contains some numerical values as well as some letters, 
thus i have

```
j = c( 5 , 6, 7, 6, 7,12 , missing , 6 ,7 8, missing , n/a, n/a, 5, 6)
```

I know this is saved as a factor with number of levels. i wanted to change the n/a into zero as that is its numerical value, but i don't know how to do that. I have used simple commands but it will not let me, the data is larger than what i have given so can not do it manually.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you wanted `levels(j)[levels(j)=='n/a'] <- 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gotcha' with factors is that assignment of a value to a position in the vector requires that the value be in the levels of the factor attribute. You can augment acceptable values in the 'levels' with the `levels<-`-function.

```
> j = factor( c( 5 , 6, 7, 6, 7,12 , 'missing' , 6 ,7, 8, 'missing' , 'n/a', 'n/a', 5, 6) 
# Notice that I corrected your code since you didn't enclose the character values in quotes 
# ,,,, and seemed to be missing a comma
> levels(j) <- c(levels(j), 0)  # append to levels; keep initial order.
> j[j=='n/a'] <- 0
> j
 [1] 5       6       7       6       7       12      missing 6      
 [9] 7       8       missing 0       0       5       6      
Levels: 12 5 6 7 8 missing n/a 0
```

This exact syntax would not apply to a situation where you had real R `NA`'s rather than 'n/a', since nothing ever `==`'s an `NA`.

And looking at this again I realized that I failed to see the beauty and simplicity of @akrun's suggestion of simply using `level<-` to modify the levels attribute "in place".

```
 levels(j)[levels(j)=='n/a'] <- 0
```

The logic of his suggestion which has the possibly desirable feature of not increasing the number of levels is that the integer values in the vector remain the same but one only needs to modify their labels within the attribute. I admit to often getting tripped up by factors in R, a personal failing I am apparently still working on.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure too but what about, even though after that you have to convert to numerical and trying to do other code to those `"missing"` because as you can see here, all is coerced to character stings:

```
j <- as.factor(c( 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 12, "missing", 6 , 7, 8, "missing" , "n/a", "n/a", 5, 6) )

gsub("n/a", 0, j)
 [1] "5"       "6"       "7"       "6"       "7"       "12"      "missing" "6"      
 [9] "7"       "8"       "missing" "0"       "0"       "5"       "6"
```

Answer (score -1):

is `j` a vector or a variable in a data frame?

if `j` is variable in a data frame you just need:

```
df[is.na(df$j)] <- 0         # change all NAs to zero
df[df$j == "missing"] <- 0   # for strings (character values)
```