# Renaming labels of a factor in R

Tags: r

I have census data of Male and Female populations organizaed by age group:

```
library(tidyverse)

url <- "https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/datasets/2010-2018/counties/asrh/cc-est2018-alldata-54.csv"

if (!file.exists("./datafiles/cc-est2018-alldata-54.csv"))
  download.file(url, destfile = "./datafiles/cc-est2018-alldata-54.csv", mode = "wb")

popSample <- read.csv("./datafiles/cc-est2018-alldata-54.csv") %>%
  filter(AGEGRP != 0 & YEAR == 1) %>%
  select("STNAME", "CTYNAME", "AGEGRP", "TOT_POP", "TOT_MALE", "TOT_FEMALE")

popSample$AGEGRP <- as.factor(popSample$AGEGRP)
```

I then plot the Male and Female population relationships, faceted by age group (1-18, which is currently **treated as a int**

```
g <- ggplot(popSample, aes(x=TOT_MALE, y=TOT_FEMALE)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5, colour="darkblue") +
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10() +
  facet_wrap(~AGEGRP) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "darkred", size=.75) +
  labs(title = "F vs. M Population across all Age Groups", x = "Total Male (log10)", y = "Total Female (log10)") +
  theme_light()

g
```

Which results in this plot: https://share.getcloudapp.com/v1ur6O4e
[image: plot]

The problem: I am trying to convert the column AGEGRP from ‘int’ to ‘factor’, and change the factors labels from “1”, “2”, “3”, … “18” to "AgeGroup1", "AgeGroup2", "AgeGroup3", … "AgeGroup18"

When I try this code, my AGEGRP column's observation values are all replaced with NAs:`popSample$AGEGRP <- factor(popSample$AGEGRP, levels = c("0 to 4", "5 to 9", "10 to 14", "15 to 19", "20 to 24", "25 to 29", "30 to 34", "35 to 39", "40 to 44", "45 to 49", "50 to 54", "55 to 59", "60 to 64", "65 to 69", "70 to 74", "75 to 79", "80 to 84", "85+"))`

https://share.getcloudapp.com/qGuo1O4y

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Do you want to change the actual factor labels, or just the labels printed on the plot facets? If just the plot, there's ideas for label functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38590004/5325862). If the labels, you can do `forcats::fct_relabel(AGEGRP, ~paste0("AgeGroup", .))`

Comment: Hey you cannot convert a factor just like that. What you need to do is this. lvls <- c("0 to 4", "5 to 9", "10 to 14", "15 to 19", "20 to 24", "25 to 29", "30 to 34", "35 to 39", "40 to 44", "45 to 49", "50 to 54", "55 to 59", "60 to 64", "65 to 69", "70 to 74", "75 to 79", "80 to 84", "85+")

Comment: Read in your popSample again, don't factor and do popSample$AGEGRP <- factor(lvls[popSample$AGEGRP] ,levels=lvls)

Comment: Instead of `popSample$AGEGRP <- as.factor(popSample$AGEGRP)` try `popSample$AGEGRP <- factor(popSample$AGEGRP, labels = c("0 to 4", "5 to 9", "10 to 14", "15 to 19", "20 to 24", "25 to 29", "30 to 34", "35 to 39", "40 to 44", "45 to 49", "50 to 54", "55 to 59", "60 to 64", "65 to 69", "70 to 74", "75 to 79", "80 to 84", "85+"))`. Note that the `levels` parameter has been replaced by `labels`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945454/how-to-change-levels-of-a-variable-that-is-a-factor

Answer (score 2):

```
popSample$AGEGRP <- factor( popSample$AGEGRP, levels = c("0 to 4", "5 to 9", "10 to 14", "15 to 19", "20 to 24", "25 to 29", "30 to 34", "35 to 39", "40 to 44", "45 to 49", "50 to 54", "55 to 59", "60 to 64", "65 to 69", "70 to 74", "75 to 79", "80 to 84", "85+"))
```

Need to add all levels though.

Alternatively

```
levels(popSample$AGEGRP) <- c("0 to 4", "5 to 9", "10 to 14", "15 to 19", "20 to 24", "25 to 29", "30 to 34", "35 to 39", "40 to 44", "45 to 49", "50 to 54", "55 to 59", "60 to 64", "65 to 69", "70 to 74", "75 to 79", "80 to 84", "85+")
```

should work as well.

Comment: Thank you kindly. I used this code here: `popSample$AGEGRP <- factor(popSample$AGEGRP, levels = c("0 to 4", "5 to 9", "10 to 14", "15 to 19", "20 to 24", "25 to 29", "30 to 34", "35 to 39", "40 to 44", "45 to 49", "50 to 54", "55 to 59", "60 to 64", "65 to 69", "70 to 74", "75 to 79", "80 to 84", "85+"))`


It didn't seem to work tho, my AGEGRP column as been replaced with NAs for all observations: https://share.getcloudapp.com/qGuo1O4y Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Read in the csv again:

```
library(tidyverse)

url <- "https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/datasets/2010-2018/counties/asrh/cc-est2018-alldata-54.csv"
popSample <- read.csv(url) %>%
filter(AGEGRP != 0 & YEAR == 1) %>%
select("STNAME", "CTYNAME", "AGEGRP", "TOT_POP", "TOT_MALE", "TOT_FEMALE")
```

If you just want to add a prefix "AgeGroup" to your facet labels, you do:

```
ggplot(popSample, aes(x=TOT_MALE, y=TOT_FEMALE)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5, colour="darkblue") +
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10() +
  facet_wrap(~AGEGRP,labeller=labeller(AGEGRP = function(i)paste0("AgeGroup",i))) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "darkred", size=.75) +
  labs(title = "F vs. M Population across all Age Groups", 
  x = "Total Male (log10)", y = "Total Female (log10)") +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

If there is a need for new factors, then you need to refactor (like @Annet's answer below):

```
lvls = c("0 to 4", "5 to 9", "10 to 14", "15 to 19", 
"20 to 24", "25 to 29", "30 to 34", "35 to 39", 
"40 to 44", "45 to 49", "50 to 54", "55 to 59",
 "60 to 64", "65 to 69", "70 to 74", "75 to 79", "80 to 84", "85+")
#because you have factorize it
# if you can read the csv again, skip the factorization
popSample$AGEGRP = factor(lvls[popSample$AGEGRP],levels=lvls)
```

Then plot:

```
ggplot(popSample, aes(x=TOT_MALE, y=TOT_FEMALE)) +
      geom_point(alpha = 0.5, colour="darkblue") +
      scale_x_log10() +
      scale_y_log10() +
      facet_wrap(~AGEGRP) +
      stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "darkred", size=.75) +
      labs(title = "F vs. M Population across all Age Groups", 
      x = "Total Male (log10)", y = "Total Female (log10)") +
      theme_light()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I think I need to refactor. Do you know how I can rename these labels to be `c("0 to 4", "5 to 9", "10 to 14", "15 to 19", "20 to 24", "25 to 29", "30 to 34", "35 to 39", "40 to 44", "45 to 49", "50 to 54", "55 to 59", "60 to 64", "65 to 69", "70 to 74", "75 to 79", "80 to 84", "85+"` for the factors 1 through 18?

Comment: Yeah I understand your question now. see above.

Answer (score -1):

To change all the factor labels with one function, you can use `forcats::fct_relabel` (`forcats` ships as part of the tidyverse, which you've already got loaded). The changed factor labels will carry over to the plot facets and the order stays the same.

First few entries:

```r
# before relabelling
popSample$AGEGRP[1:4]
#> [1] 1 2 3 4
#> Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18

# after relabelling
forcats::fct_relabel(popSample$AGEGRP, ~paste0("AgeGroup", .))[1:4]
#> [1] AgeGroup1 AgeGroup2 AgeGroup3 AgeGroup4
#> 18 Levels: AgeGroup1 AgeGroup2 AgeGroup3 AgeGroup4 AgeGroup5 ... AgeGroup18
```

Or with base R, reassign the levels:

```r
levels(popSample$AGEGRP) <- paste0("AgeGroup", levels(popSample$AGEGRP))
popSample$AGEGRP[1:4]
#> [1] AgeGroup1 AgeGroup2 AgeGroup3 AgeGroup4
#> 18 Levels: AgeGroup1 AgeGroup2 AgeGroup3 AgeGroup4 AgeGroup5 ... AgeGroup18
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know how I could rename the factor labels to be  `c("0 to 4", "5 to 9", "10 to 14", "15 to 19", "20 to 24", "25 to 29", "30 to 34", "35 to 39", "40 to 44", "45 to 49", "50 to 54", "55 to 59", "60 to 64", "65 to 69", "70 to 74", "75 to 79", "80 to 84", "85+"` rather than Agegroup1, 2, 3 etc?

Comment: Sure, but now you're asking a slightly different question, since as far as I can tell those age groups aren't in your data already

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion: those age groups are the same as 1:18, I just need to rename them. In other words, agegroup = 1 should have the label "0 to 4", agegroup =2 should have the lavel "5 to 9" and so on. Thank you so much for helping someone who is new to this,

Comment: If you want to do that programmatically, i.e. not by writing levels out by hand which can be error-prone, you'll either need a lookup table or figure out the pattern of the interval endpoints. But that's getting into a different (but doable) question. I'm pretty sure there's a lookup I've used out of the same bunch of Census pop estimate datasets