# I cant seem to change a variable's data

Tags: r

I'm trying to follow some practice videos on youtube, and in the video its reading a excel file and its changing the value of "condition' from "A","B" to "Control","Experimental" but it does not work for me. The data is still A,B

```
rt_df <- read.csv(file="../data/week2.csv",header=TRUE)
levels(rt_df$condition) <- factor(c("Control","Experimental"))
```

Comment: You should do `rt_df$condition <- factor(rt_df$condition, c("A", "B"), c("Control","Experimental"))`

Comment: Onyambu is of course correct, but it is helpful to realize that the arguments to `factor()` are `x =`, `levels = ` and `labels =`.

Comment: you culd also use `dplyr::recode(rt_df$condition, A = "Control", B = "Experimental")` you could also use `forcats::fct_recode` etx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming labels of a factor in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60242222/renaming-labels-of-a-factor-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this several ways in base R:

```
rt_df$condition <- ifelse(rt_df$condition == "A", "Control", "Experimental")
```

Or with a named vector:

```
v <- c("A" = "Control", "B" = "Experimental")

rt_df$condition <- v[rt_df$condition]
```

Or with logical vectors:

```
isA <- rt_df$condition == "A"
rtdf$condition[isA] <- "Control"
rtdf$condition[!isA] <- "Experimental"
```

If you need it as a `factor` then you can apply the function after recoding. If you do need it as a `factor` it would be best to use the comment from @Onyambu.